# Something wrong with this definition of absolute value function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

In Spivak's book on calculus, the absolute value function has been defined as:

$$|x| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  -x & \mbox{if } x \leq 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

The use of equality in both the parts makes me uncomfortable. Up to now in my life, I've always seen this function defined as $-x$ if $x < 0$. As I see it, this only introduces ambiguity when $x=0$ (yes, one can argue that $0$ and $-0$ are the same thing, but why complicate matters? I'm wondering if this is a typo or something rigorous that is escaping me.

Comment: I mean it's not going to matter because like you said at $0$, $x$ and $-x$ are going to agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not define absolute value by $|y|=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}y,&amp;y\geq0\\-y,&amp;y\leq0\end{cases}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186915/why-not-define-absolute-value-by-y-begincases-phantom-y-y-geq0-y-y-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. This is not a typo.

Comment: Hmmm. Differentiability hasn't been introduced yet, so I'm going to accept your answer on face value. It still beats me as to why can't we separate out the equality part and add a third condition.

Comment: Say what? This isn't germane. And, typo or not, it's highly unusual not to list mutually exclusive cases.

Comment: @dotslash Differentiability of $y$ is the existence of the differential $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$: $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\dfrac{y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yes, the books tell me that much, although it will be while before I reach there and see how it actually makes a difference. For now I'll just live with the idea that there is something important not to be overlooked. :)