# Why not define absolute value by $|y|=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}y,&y\geq0\\-y,&y\leq0\end{cases}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, absolute-value

I know that there are some discussion over the definition over absolute value in stack-exchange. However, I did not satisfied. It is generally given that $$
\left| y \right| = 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}y, & y \geq 0 \\ 
-y, & y < 0
\end{cases}
$$

However, I think that this definition is a little bit dangerous, because it may give rise to wrong answer in some questions such that

> Write all possible values of $x$ in $|2x-6|=6-2x$

If students use the foregoing definition, they will write $-1,-2,-3,\ldots$. However, $0$ should have been included.

I know that this will seem ridiculous to most of you, but when we imagine ourselves like a primary or secondary school students, it may cause problem.

So, my question is why most of book use this definition instead of  clearer one such that $$\left| y \right| = 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}y, & y \geq 0 \\ 
-y, & y \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Your "definition" is only valid once you have proved the theorem that the relation you have written down is in fact a function. Why not stick with the simpler and correct definition?

Comment: Your version seems much worse to most of us, since $y=0$ comes up in two different cases. Would $|y|=\begin{cases}y,&y\ge0,\\-y,&y\le0,\\17,&y=17,\\32,&y=-32.\end{cases}$ be even "clearer"???

Comment: "If students use the foregoing definition , they will write −1,−2,−3,." Why would they do such a silly thing?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't even understand whar Martin means by that.

Comment: It is common practice that when writing a piece-wise defined function, $f(x)=\begin{cases}f_1(x)&\text{if }x\in A_1\\f_2(x)&\text{if }x\in A_2\\\vdots\end{cases}$ that $A_1,A_2,\dots$ form a partition of the domain, that is to say the cases do not overlap and the cases are exhaustive.  This allows the reader to rest easy that the function is not malformed by accidentally having some input who falls into no cases and so is undefined or having some input who falls into multiple cases and might have mapped to different values in each of those cases in which case it would be illdefined.

Comment: You could define absolute value as $|x| = \max\{x, -x\}$ instead which imo is cleaner.

Comment: Now... insisting that $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are mutually exclusive allows us to know as readers that there is no $x$ that has different outputs *without having to check*.  If you allow your cases to overlap, we ought to verify that the overlaps in cases actually all yield the same result.

Comment: Consider... $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2+3&\text{if }x\geq 0\\x^2-3&\text{if }x\leq 0\end{cases}$  This function is illdefined since $f(0)$ is simultaneously $+3$ per the first case and $-3$ per the second case.  It may be clear at a glance that this is a problem for this example, but larger examples where it becomes harder to evaluate a function at a quick glance, we shouldn't force that duty on the reader.

Comment: @JMoravitz Well, if $x \geq 0$ ,then $-x \leq 0$ ,so $-x \leq x$ and $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=x$ . If $x \leq 0$ , then $-x \geq 0$ ,i.e, $x \leq -x$ and  $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=-x$ . So is it not a proof for my "clearer" definition

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, if $x \geq 0$ ,then $-x \leq 0$ ,so $-x \leq x$ and $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=x$ . If $x \leq 0$ , then $-x \geq 0$ ,i.e, $x \leq -x$ and  $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=-x$ . So is it not a proof for my "clearer" definition

Comment: Your "definition" (*which isn't even a different definition than the one already given*) is not "incorrect."  It is just presented in a non-traditional way which directly goes against common best practices.  The formatting is what is incorrect, not the content.  As for it being "clearer", no I disagree, it does not clarify anything and instead actively harms the readability.

Comment: If the (not-entirely-unreasonable) concern is that students will overlook the key "$y=0$" case when their attention has been largely on $y<0$, then perhaps it would be better still to separate-out this key case to make it harder to ignore; ie,  $$|y|:=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}y,& y>0\\\phantom{-}0,& y=0\\-y,&y<0\end{cases}$$ At least this form doesn't violate the nonoverlapping-domains convention for defining piecewise functions. (It's perhaps a little *inefficient*, but eventually students encounter the one-liner definition $|y|:=\sqrt{y^2}$, anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

I fail to see what's non-clear about the usual definition. The definition that you suggest is logically correct, but may put it the mind of the students that there is no problem in defining a function with an expression such as$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\text{some expression}&\text{ if }x\geqslant a\\\text{some other expression}&\text{ if }x\leqslant a.\end{cases}$$And there is no problem in the definition that you have suggested. But, in general, you can't do that.

Comment: For OP: the key point here is the word *function*. Functions are not multi-valued (by definition). You could define a *relation* along these lines, but most of math does not work with relations at large because they don't have enough structure.

Comment: Well, if $x \geq 0$ ,then $-x \leq 0$ ,so $-x \leq x$ and $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=x$ . If $x \leq 0$ , then $-x \geq 0$ ,i.e, $x \leq -x$ and  $|x|=max \{x,-x\}=-x$ . So is it not a proof for my "clearer" definition

Comment: if we used the former , i would not reach that proof

Comment: So , doesnt this proof show that my clearer definition is not "illdefined"

Comment: @Martin It is not ill-defined as multiple people have said already. The problem is that this does not work in general, for example you could not define $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$ as this, as Cameron Williams pointed out, is not a function. As the language you use to describe a mathematical phenomenon usually aims to apply to a general class of phenomena, your notation might not be so sensible.